# How do I query the results of a MongoDB view (or aggregation) in NodeJS?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have created a view (or aggregation) using Studio 3T and saved it. I would now like to simply display the results on my mobile app using NodeJS. When I do so, all I get in return is an empty array. Am I required to regenerate the aggregation (or view) in my code each time or is it possible to access the data from the view with a simple query?

Comment: We can't really tell what might be wrong with the code without seeing any.

Comment: I was trying to create the view in Studio 3T then just query the results. I decided to put the aggregation code in my backend code and it works just fine. I was attempting the old school way like when using Oracle or SQL Server. Thanks,